# git pull origin master with no files changing

Tags: git

Is there a way to pull all the commits from a remote repository to a local active branch without changing the files? And then to continue working with the directory as ususal (git status, git commit etc.)

I'd like to get the same result as copying the .git folder from another repository of the same project.

Answer (score 0):

`git fetch` will pull local changes without merging them.

Comment: No, you cannot update without changing the files. It will simply fetch the changes of the remote repository without merging them in your workspace.

Comment: The answer to your question @phgrey is to run `git fetch` you said you wanted to pull down changes without merging. If you want a new repository, then I would recommend cloning something else.

Comment: @I.am.michiel your comment is confusing - git fetch does not modify a working copy.